# Golang io/ioutil NopCloser

Tags: go, reader

Does anyone have a good or any explanation of Golang's [`NopCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) function? 
 I looked around but failed to find anything besides Golang's main doc's explanation of:

> NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the
>   provided Reader r.

Any pointers or explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whenever you need to return an [`io.ReadCloser`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser), while making sure a `Close()` is available, you can use a `NopCloser` to build such a ReaderCloser.

You can see one example in this [fork of gorest](https://github.com/fromkeith/gorest), in [`util.go`](https://github.com/fromkeith/gorest/blob/master/util.go)

```
//Marshals the data in interface i into a byte slice, using the Marhaller/Unmarshaller specified in mime.
//The Marhaller/Unmarshaller must have been registered before using gorest.RegisterMarshaller
func InterfaceToBytes(i interface{}, mime string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Bool:
        x := v.Bool()
        if x {
            return ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("true"))), nil
        }
```

Answer (score 19):

It's used for functions that require `io.ReadCloser` but your current object (for example a `bytes.Buffer`) doesn't provide a Close function.

Comment: ioutil.NopCloser only wraps io.Reader. You can create your own equivalent to produce an io.WriteCloser

Comment: It also has uses where you want to be able to read from it multiple times, without losing the content, as in this example: https://medium.com/@xoen/golang-read-from-an-io-readwriter-without-loosing-its-content-2c6911805361

Answer (score 4):

It is for when you need to supply an item that has a `Close` function, but when
`Close` doesn't really make sense for that item. As such, the function pretty much
does nothing:

```
func (nopCloser) Close() error { return nil }
```

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.3/src/io/io.go#L620