# How do I turn an io.Reader into a io.ReadCloser?

Tags: go

I have an `io.Reader` that doesn't require closing:

```
stringReader := strings.NewReader("shiny!")
```

And I want to pass it to a method that receives an `io.ReadCloser`

```
func readAndClose(source io.ReadCloser) {
    ...
}
```

How do I turn the `io.Reader` into a `io.ReadCloser` without specially creating a struct that implements the `Close` method?

Comment: FYI: this question has been marked as duplicate, but it's in fact a different question. The answer to both questions is the same though, but that's not a reason to mark the question as a duplicate. ;-)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you're certain that your `io.Reader` doesn't require any actual closing, you can wrap it with an [`ioutil.NopCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser).

#### Go 1.16 Update

As of version 1.16 `ioutil.NopCloser` is [deprecated](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#ioutil).

`NopCloser` has been moved to [`io`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#NopCloser):

```
stringReader := strings.NewReader("shiny!")
stringReadCloser := io.NopCloser(stringReader)
```

#### Go 1.15 and older

From the godoc:

> NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the provided Reader r.

So we can apply it like:

```
stringReader := strings.NewReader("shiny!")
stringReadCloser := ioutil.NopCloser(stringReader)
```

Comment: The above is my question and I couldn't find the answer in StackOverflow. I found it buried in some forum posts and I thought it might be nice to share.

The "Answer your own question" checkbox does state "share your knowledge, Q&A-style". What's disingenuous about that?

Comment: @Adrian as someone who's been around SO for 10 years, you ought to be aware that this community is perfectly fine with answering your own questions.

Comment: First result searching SO for `reader readcloser`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158990/golang-io-ioutil-nopcloser

Comment: everything was already on the internet more than once _before_ SO.  so be it.  long live closing duplicates.  long live duplicates.  Thanks, @noamt

Comment: Whats the way to do this without `iotuil` it is deprecated as of 1.16 golang

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer